# ListView in xml, setting Adapter to

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have following code:

```
public class ShowActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //       setContentView(R.layout.show_list);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                BaseColumns._ID,
                DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_NAME,
                DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_AMOUNT,
                DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_UNIT,
                DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_PPU,
                DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_TOTAL,
                DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_COMMENT};

        Cursor c = managedQuery(ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
        String[] columns = new String[]{BaseColumns._ID,ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_NAME, ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_AMOUNT, ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_UNIT, ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_PPU, ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_TOTAL, ContentProviderMetaData.DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_COMMENT};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.lname,R.id.lamount,R.id.lunit,R.id.lppu,R.id.ltotal,R.id.lcomment};
        Log.d("ShowActivity","Cursor, columns, to set - now setting adapter");
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_entry, c, columns, to);
     //   ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        this.setListAdapter(simpleadapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    //    intentCheck();
    }
```

It works fine, but as you might have seen at my comments, i don't want to create the listview via getListView(), i want to do a usual setContentView(R.Layout.---) and populate a Listview, which is defined there. But all tutorials I have seen yet do it like that, and I have no clue how to change that to my wishes.

How does my layout-xml have to look like? how do i "tell him to use it" ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use directly setContentView(R.layout.main); on a ListActivity as long as you define a listView with the android:list id on your xml:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            />
```

To set the adapter call directly setListAdapter from your ListActivity

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ListActivity as your base class, extend Activity, set your content to the layout, grab a reference to your expanded ListView (findViewById(...)) and then handle setting the adapter that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

No change needed in the .xml